# Replacing backslash followed by newline with space using awk

Tags: unix, awk, newline

I have a file which has contents in the following format:

```
string1 = string2.a \
          string3.a \
          string4.a
string5 = random
```

Output file required is:

```
string1 =  string2.a string3.a string4.a
string5 = random
```

I tried following:

```
gawk '{ gsub(/\\n/," ");print }' inputfile > outputfile
```

but it did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not restricted to awk, there's a sed solution in the [sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.25):

```
sed -e :a -e '/\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!f&&/=/{s=""; s=s FS $0;f=1;next}f&&!/=/{s=s FS $0}f&&/=/{f=0;print s;print;next} ' file
```

I don't know if there really is a "\" , if there is, use `gsub()` as appropriate

Comment: I am newbee to this scripting. But still trying ur command lead me to the following error message:  "f&&/=/{s="";: Event not found"

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  /\\$/ {
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "")     # trim leading whitespace
    sub(/[[:space:]]+\\$/, " ")  # remove the trailing backslash
    line = line $0
    next
  }
  line {
      printf("%s", line)
      line = ""
      sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "")
  }
  1
'
```

Comment: Am getting variable syntax error message for ur set of commands.

Comment: @ankush, what's a "variable syntax error"? please show the actual error message. did you cut and paste this code exactly?